# How to get the generated key of the saveValue method in Polymerfire?

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

So I'm using this [method saveValue](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/elements/firebase-document#method-saveValue) and only using the path parameter. The method is generating a unique key and data is stored while I'm inserting text in my input fields...

My question now is: How can I get to know what the new key is?

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but I just came across this issue.  The answer is that the new path is saved to the path property of the firebase-document used to call saveValue.

```
<firebase-document id="NewUserSync"></firebase-document>
```

...In some click handler....

```
this.$.NewUserSync.path = null;
this.$.NewUserSync.data = OrgData;
this.$.NewUserSync.saveValue(`/Customer_Orgs/`).then(resp => {
            console.log(this.$.NewUserSync.path);
            // /Customer_Orgs/-LH_pEzgWJpv3mpYYTuA     

          })
```